# SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: javascript, typescript, solana

How to fix this Solana error?

throw new SendTransactionError(
^
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4546:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4505:20)
at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:4493:12)
at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\util\send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21)
at async main (C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\Desktop\mpl\main.ts:63:18) {
logs: []
}

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: "Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit."

This means that you're trying to move SOL from an account with no SOL.  If you're on devnet / testnet / localnet, you can airdrop SOL directly to the account with `solana airdrop 1 <ACCOUNT_PUBKEY>`.

Comment: Well I'm on mainnet and I do have enough SOL for the transactions.

Comment: PS C:\Users\Alisa'sTech\Desktop\mpl> solana balance
0.04442984 SOL

Comment: In that case, some other account isn't funded.  Could you provide some more information about what you're trying to do and the code that you're running?